# Convert Inkscape .sla files into pdf from a script

Tags: command-line, macros, x11, inkscape

I have over one-hundred `.sla` files that I'd like to convert to PDF. In Inkscape it can be done in the gui `file > export > save as PDF` etc. but I'm lazy and will mess it up. I'd really like to just automate this in a script. Is there a way to do this?

I haven't found an Inkscape way, but perhaps I can automate OSX to do my clicking for me or some other macro style solution? Inkscape runs under X11 quartz stuff which complicates things...

Comment: Have you tried exporting from the command line with the `--export-pdf` option? Try a script similar to [this one](https://gastarbeiten.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/batch-convert-svg-to-png-with-inkscape-command-line/). In OSX you may need to call it from an xterm.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. It only seemed to work if the input was `.svg` and not `.sla`

Comment: Doesn't `.sla` belong to Scribus, not Inkscape? In that case, you could use [`sla2pdf`](https://github.com/sla2pdf-team/sla2pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to my question, but I solved my problem another way so I'm posting here in case it helps someone:

Context, I auto-generated 100 `.sla` files by modifying a template one I made by hand. Each of these were for wedding placenames. I then planned to convert each of these PDFs into images.

My work-around was to modify the template to have 100 identical pages, I then wrote a script to mutate that template so that I had my 100 different pages (guest names). Then I could just export a single PDF and ultimately, convert that PDF into 100 images.